# Best way to save and read large files?

Tags: sql, database, flutter, data-structures, save

I'm trying to create a whitelabel streaming/cloud file management tool for mobile + Windows systems. The goal is to be able to view remote content and download it with the app serving as "proxy" for the files- only the app can open them, when downloading it encrypts & saves data locally. Currently I've tried [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) [SQLite3](https://pub.dev/packages/sqlite3) and right now I'm starting all over with [Isar](https://isar.dev/).

None of the above solutions work well with files over 2GB. Hive takes 7 minutes to save & encrypt 3GB data blob. What's worse saved file is over 9GB total. SQLite does a better job at 3.5 minutes while also decreasing final file size but that also seems like too long of a process.

Another thing is when encrypting & saving data processor, memory & disk usage are at 99% all the time on a Windows machine. I don't want to imagine how hard that process would hit a phone from like 2017.

1. is there any way to optimize whole saving process while limiting hardware usage?
2. How can this be done faster & more efficient or slower but with usages being in mid 70% so that user can comfortably do other tasks on the machine while waiting?
3. Is noSQL box solution better in this instance than SQL structure?
4. Can I split save data to chunks to have more of less intense saving operations without damaging files?
5. How does Netflix or Disney+ save over 3hr of HD movie with a couple subtitle languages so effortlessly?
6. Is there any good source on save-download operation and how to intercept it with external software? Classic downloading saves data instantly while downloading it I just can't figure out how to do the same with extra steps.

Comment: why would want to save 2GB files as blobs in the database? cannot you simply store your files in a normal filesystem?

Comment: Figured it would be easier for the system to save pure data as-is than regular file type. This way of thinking also seems appropriate as the goal is for the data to not be accessible in any way outside of this specific program. So not only pure blob but safely encrypted one. In my mind it sounds like more layers of security as potential attacker would have a harder time knowing what file it's originally.

Comment: in what chunk size do you divide your files in blobs? maybe the chunk sizes are to big? is it few MB, more than 10MB or even bigger?

Comment: As of now I only split chunks by file, so file1 may be 5mb and file2 may be 2gb,  In between files I have custom "save separator" to be able to split them back up into separate items after reading file with the app. I was worried that chunking may result in data loss or file corruption that's why files are saved as a whole.

Comment: wait, so you are reading the whole 2GB file into memory? I mean you have `List<int>` with 2 billion items?

Comment: For debugging purposes- yes I store it in memory to test different saving methods.

Comment: Is there some code you can add to your question (not in comments), to give us an idea of where your slowdown is? Disk read times are on the order of 20 seconds per gigabyte, and write will be somewhat slower, so there is a definite limit on how quickly you can do things. But that's just I/O time. If it's taking 7 minutes to encrypt and save, then there's likely some heavy lifting in your encryption code. Let us see it.

Comment: `invertBits` does the job in 2 minutes on a 2.9gb file. I've also managed to cut down significantly on memory usage (consistently under 200mb) with custom download and download interceptors, and save time is under 2 minutes without encryption with the file being saved at the same time as its getting downloaded. Still question being is the data more safe without a database? Is it more efficient code-wise to store raw encrypted files and reverse encryption with keys when using files through the app? Also won't adding chunks encypted separately to a single file damage data?

Comment: so do you need to store locally "open" (not encypted files?) or all you want is to get the data from the internet and store it locally encrypted? if the latter case you can get and crypt them without storing the open version locally

Comment: Yes, I need the latter. The files must be unusable and preferably untraceable outside the program that manages these files. That's why I was experimenting with keeping them in memory and that's why I made custom download interceptor to save, encrypt and hide them during the download process. Still I don't really know how to do these things effectively without damaging data and if it's better to store them as files or in database.

Comment: I know `contentLength` is nullable. Right now I need the most efficient way to read encrypted data either way if it's encrypted raw or it's pure byte data with sha265 for example. Whitch would be more safe for the end user and the program.

Comment: btw storing the files in sqlite or hive does not add any security benefits as it would take less then 15 minutes to figure out the database format and read the encrypted files

Comment: I'm currently trying out your solution. On a 2.8GB file it took 176.6 seconds, and ram usage was under 400mb.

Comment: ram usage was 400M? during reading the file? I don't see any reason why it would happen as I don't use any internal `List<int>` for file content. Hmmm... Any difference if you don't use blowfish encryption?

Comment: Maybe that's what flutter as engine needs + caching some http dumps on windows. That's a good result nonetheless. Now let's see if utf8 decoder will tell me that file is broken as it happened with other encryption methods (xor/aes) ;)

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine, both saving and reading files, and blowfish from what I've gathered seems to be a respected encryption algorithm. If you post your comments as an answer I'll mark it as a desired answer for the question. Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: I didn't switch to AES yet, now is the boring part of the process- discusing online authentication features with backend devs, and final visuals with designing team. Decrypting with your solution, although slightly modified to use custom version of random access file to decrypt and display only parts of file that user is currently viewing is almost instantaneous. Without raf decrypting fully a 8.05 mb txt file takes between 0.7 to 1 second and increasing depending on system utilization by other apps. Videos over 1gb are taken over with functions similar to raf for optimization so no raw times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code (it uses [blowfish_ecb](https://pub.dev/packages/blowfish_ecb) encryption algorithm but any other can be used as well), notice that when decrypting we dont have to wrap the original stream and use it directly (`return (encrypt? makeBigChunksAndPadZeros(inStream, inStreamLength, outMap) : inStream)`)

```
class FooWidget1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FooWidget1> createState() => _FooWidget1State();
}

class _FooWidget1State extends State<FooWidget1> {
  final notifier = ValueNotifier(0.0);
  Duration timeSpan = Duration.zero;
  Map<String, dynamic> out = {};
  String status = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final start = DateTime.now();
              int length;
              File inFile;
              File outFile;

          // case 1: encrypting from network
              // final uri = Uri.parse('http://0.0.0.0:8000/open.mp4');
              // final response = await http.Request('get', uri).send();
              // // print(response.headers);
              // length = response.contentLength!;
              // outFile = File('secret.file');
              // setState(() {
              //   status = 'encrypting\n\nsrc: [$uri]\ndst: [$outFile]\nlength: $length bytes';
              // });
              // out = await crypt(
              //   encrypt: true,
              //   key: 'foo bar key',
              //   inStream: response.stream,
              //   inStreamLength: length,
              //   outFile: outFile,
              //   notifier: notifier,
              // );
          // end of case 1

          // case 2: encrypting from file
              // inFile = File('open.mp4');
              // length = await inFile.length();
              // outFile = File('secret.file');
              // setState(() {
              //   status = 'encrypting\n\nsrc: [$inFile]\ndst: [$outFile]\nlength: $length bytes';
              // });
              // out = await crypt(
              //   encrypt: true,
              //   key: 'foo bar key',
              //   inStream: inFile.openRead(),
              //   inStreamLength: length,
              //   outFile: outFile,
              //   notifier: notifier,
              // );
          // end of case 2

          // case 3: decrypting from file
              inFile = File('secret.file');
              length = await inFile.length();
              outFile = File('open1.mp4');
              setState(() {
                status = 'decrypting\n\nsrc: [$inFile]\ndst: [$outFile]\nlength: $length bytes';
              });
              out = await crypt(
                encrypt: false,
                key: 'foo bar key',
                inStream: inFile.openRead(),
                inStreamLength: length,
                outFile: outFile,
                notifier: notifier,
                pad: 7,
              );
          // end of case 3

              timeSpan = DateTime.now().difference(start);
              setState(() {
                status = status + '\n\ntook: ${timeSpan.inMilliseconds / 1000}s\npad: ${out['pad']}';
              });
            },
            child: const Text('start crypting'),
          ),
          SizedBox.fromSize(
            size: const Size.square(100),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: notifier,
                builder: (ctx, child) => CircularProgressIndicator(value: notifier.value),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(status, textScaleFactor: 1.5),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> crypt({
    bool encrypt = true,
    required String key,
    required Stream<List<int>> inStream,
    required int inStreamLength,
    required File outFile,
    ValueNotifier<double>? notifier,
    int pad = 0,
  }) async {
    int readBytes = 0;
    double oldValue = 0;

    // it needs: import 'package:blowfish_ecb/blowfish_ecb.dart';
    final blowfishECB = BlowfishECB(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(key)));

    List<int> mapper(List<int> data) {
      if (notifier != null && inStreamLength > 0) {
        readBytes += data.length;
        final currentValue = readBytes / inStreamLength;
        if (currentValue > oldValue + 0.01) {
          oldValue = currentValue;
          notifier.value = currentValue;
        }
      }

      if (encrypt) {
        data = blowfishECB.encode(data);
      } else {
        data = blowfishECB.decode(data);
        if (readBytes == inStreamLength && pad != 0) {
          // the last chunk with non zero [pad]
          print('crypt: removing $pad byte(s)');
          data = data.sublist(0, data.length - pad);
        }
      }
      return data;
    }

    final outMap = {
      'size': 0,
      'pad': 0,
    };

    return (encrypt? makeBigChunksAndPadZeros(inStream, inStreamLength, outMap) : inStream)
      .map(mapper)
      .pipe(outFile.openWrite())
      .then((value) => outMap..['size'] = readBytes);
  }

  Stream<List<int>> makeBigChunksAndPadZeros(Stream<List<int>> inStream, int inStreamLength, Map outMap) async* {
    // TODO make it bigger / smaller
    const chunkSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    int index = 0;
    final reader = ChunkedStreamReader(inStream);
    while (true) {
      var chunk = await reader.readChunk(chunkSize);
      index += chunk.length;
      if (index != inStreamLength) {
        // normal chunk
        yield chunk;
      } else {
        // the last chunk
        if (chunk.isNotEmpty) {
          // not empty chunk: add zeroes if needed
          final pad = 8 - chunk.length % 8;
          if (pad != 8) {
            print('makeBigChunksAndPadZeros: adding $pad zero(s)');
            chunk = List.of(chunk.followedBy(List.filled(pad, 0)));
            outMap['pad'] = pad;
          }
          yield chunk;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```