Flutter. Decoding and working with large files
I'm using the pointycastle library and the cbc encryption (although I don't think it matters much). I need to open a file, decrypt a part of it, replace the encrypted part with the decrypted part, and read the file in the viewer. But sometimes I get an "out of memory" error, and for large files 100+Mb, it takes a long time. Especially on older devices. Is there a way to optimize it somehow? Or at least clear the memory or something?
 Future<void> _getFile() async {
    final File file = File('file_path.PDF');

    final Uint8List list = await file.readAsBytes();

    final Uint8List decryptPart = _aesCbcDecrypt(
      key: 'key',
      iv: 'vector',
      file: list.sublist(0, 1040),
    );
    _memoryBytes = Uint8List.fromList(<int>[...decryptPart, ...list.sublist(1040)]);

    setState(() {});
  }

Uint8List _aesCbcDecrypt({required Uint8List key, required Uint8List iv, required Uint8List file}) {
    final CBCBlockCipher cbc = CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine())
      ..init(false, ParametersWithIV<CipherParameters?>(KeyParameter(key), iv));

    final Uint8List decryptFile = Uint8List(file.length);

    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < file.length) {
      offset += cbc.processBlock(file, offset, decryptFile, offset);
    }
    return decryptFile.sublist(0, 1024);
  }


try Streams, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75006173/best-way-to-save-and-read-large-files#75069606

yes there is. Don't try to read the file into memory in one go. await file.readAsBytes(); Consider using RandomAccessFile to read manageable chunks into memory, or, as in @pskink example above, use streams. The trick to interface streams to ciphers with fixed block sizes is ChunkedStreamReader: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/ChunkedStreamReader-class.html

Further note that, while pointycastle is nice, generic, complete and easy, it is not fast as it implements the AES round in software. If you can change from AES-CBC to, say, AES-GCM you can find libraries that implement this using processor-accelerated instructions (like lazysodium).
