Flutter: I get an error while decrypting the file in chunks
I have an encrypted file and I want to decrypt it the key and IV is saved in sqflite database and I get it from 'downloadedAudioModel' and then load the decrypted bytes to my audioPlayer

I have this function to decrypt and it works fine (But it takes long time for 10MB file to load "I think because it load all the encrypted bytes to the memory and then decrypt it"):

  static Future<void> decryptAndLoadFile(
      DownloadedAudioModel downloadedAudioModel) async {
    String password = downloadedAudioModel.key ?? "";
    final ivBase64 = downloadedAudioModel.encIV ?? "";

    final directory = await getDownloadsDirectory();
    final downloadDirectory = Directory(directory!.path);

    final encryptedFile = File(
        '${downloadDirectory.path}/songs/${downloadedAudioModel.songPath}.encrypted');
    final encryptedBytes = await encryptedFile.readAsBytes();
      final key = enc.Key.fromUtf8(password);
      List<int> iv = base64Decode(ivBase64).toList();
      final encrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key));

      final decryptedBytes = encrypter.decryptBytes(enc.Encrypted(encryptedBytes),
          iv: enc.IV(Uint8List.fromList(iv)));
      await MyGlobals.audioPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(
          Uri.dataFromBytes(decryptedBytes),
          tag: MediaItem(
              id: downloadedAudioModel.id.toString(),
              title: downloadedAudioModel.songName!,
              artist: downloadedAudioModel.authorName,
              artUri: Uri.file(
                  "${downloadDirectory.path}/avatars/${downloadedAudioModel.songAvatar}"))));
  }

I tried using stream and getting the encrypted bytes in chunks and decrypting the chunk for faster loading:

I tried using openRead function that return Stream<List<int>> to get chunks of the encrypted file:

    final encryptedFile = File(
        '${downloadDirectory.path}/songs/${downloadedAudioModel.songPath}.encrypted');
    encryptedFile.openRead().forEach((element) {
      final decryptedBytes = encrypter.decryptBytes(
          enc.Encrypted(Uint8List.fromList(element)),
          iv: enc.IV(Uint8List.fromList(iv)));
    });

But when it start decrypting I get an exception error in decryptBytes(...) function:

ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block)


I also tried this using loop:

static Stream<List<int>> decryptFile(
      DownloadedAudioModel downloadedAudioModel,
      Directory downloadDirectory) async* {
    String password = downloadedAudioModel.key ?? "";
    final ivBase64 = downloadedAudioModel.encIV ?? "";

    final encryptedFile = File(
        '${downloadDirectory.path}/songs/${downloadedAudioModel.songPath}.encrypted');

    final encryptedBytes = await encryptedFile.readAsBytes();

    final key = enc.Key.fromUtf8(password);
    List<int> iv = base64Decode(ivBase64).toList();
    final encrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key));

    try {
      int i = 0;
      while (i < encryptedBytes.length) {
        final chunk = encryptedBytes.sublist(
            i, math.min(i + 4096, encryptedBytes.length));
        final decryptedChunk =
            _decryptChunk(encrypter, enc.IV(Uint8List.fromList(iv)), chunk);
        yield decryptedChunk;
        i += 4096;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is FormatException &&
          e.message.contains('Invalid or corrupted pad block')) {
        yield* Stream.error(
          Exception(
              'Error decrypting file: The provided password is incorrect or the file is corrupted.'),
        );
      } else {
        yield* Stream.error(e);
      }
    }
  }

  static List<int> _decryptChunk(
      enc.Encrypter encrypter, enc.IV iv, List<int> encryptedChunk) {
    final encrypted = enc.Encrypted(Uint8List.fromList(encryptedChunk));
    try {
      final decryptedChunk = encrypter.decryptBytes(encrypted, iv: iv);
      return decryptedChunk;
    } catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }

  static Future<void> playDecryptedAudio(
      DownloadedAudioModel downloadedAudioModel) async {
    final directory = await getDownloadsDirectory();
    final downloadDirectory = Directory(directory!.path);
    try {
      final decryptedStream =
          decryptFile(downloadedAudioModel, downloadDirectory);

      final decryptedBytes = await decryptedStream.fold<List<int>>(
        [],
        (previousValue, element) => [...previousValue, ...element],
      );
      
      await MyGlobals.audioPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(
          Uri.dataFromBytes(decryptedBytes),
          tag: MediaItem(
              id: downloadedAudioModel.id.toString(),
              title: downloadedAudioModel.songName!,
              artist: downloadedAudioModel.authorName,
              artUri: Uri.file(
                  "${downloadDirectory.path}/avatars/${downloadedAudioModel.songAvatar}"))));

      await MyGlobals.audioPlayer.play();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error playing decrypted audio: $e');
    }
  }

And I still get the same exception error
Is there any way that I can load the file faster also if the file is large

try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75006173/best-way-to-save-and-read-large-files/75069606#75069606 - it uses blowfish, not aes, first runl it as it is, then replace it with your aes (just change Future<Map<String, dynamic>> crypt({ method)

Okay I will try it

I get 3 errors The method 'ChunkedStreamReader' isn't defined for the type 'MyCustomSource'. and A value of type 'double' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'. in chunk.length and The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. I didn't want to change anything to not break the code and ask you better :)

And what about the IV in your function i didnt find it or is it not important to decrypt the file?

in the function makeBigChunksAndPadZeros(...) and in the while loop: index += chunk.length; Maybe because the: var chunk = await reader.readChunk(chunkSize); The readChunk returns InvalidType and the error could be from the ChunkedStreamReader The method 'ChunkedStreamReader' isn't defined I looked at that site but idk how to fix it

you need import 'package:async/async.dart'; - it is part of flutter sdk

Okay thanks it is good now I will change the functions to AES and try it

when decrypting you need to provide a valid pad in my case it was pad: 7, - this pad is obtained while encrypting

The default is: PKCS7 when i encrypted the file idk if it is the one you mean pad

what PKCS7 do you mean? pad is basically file length % 8 - it is also printed in the logs when encrypting the file

The padding in enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key)); the default is PKCS7 so to get the pad I should get the file length and % 8?

Ok, first did you try blowfish algorithm? was it fast enough? If so, use your aes but you gotta do that by yourself

I will try right now

In your code in the decrypting part there is outFile = File('open1.mp4') what it is about?

this is an output file

I dont want output file for my encrypted file I want to decrypt it and get the bytes and load it in audioPlayer

Can you please give an example by editing your code please

The encrypt package uses the CTR mode and PKCS#7 padding by default (i.e. it does not automatically disable padding for stream cipher modes like CTR). Since your file is decryptable with the first code, CTR and PKCS#7 are obviously required. Therefore, it is probably less effort to adapt the current code instead of a new one (with a different algorithm, mode and padding).

For chunkwise decryption to work, padding must be disabled with the exception of the last chunk. In addition, the associated IV must be determined for each chunk. For CTR: The given IV is used for the first chunk. Then the IV is increased by n for each subsequent chunk (where n is the number of blocks in a chunk), s. here.
